# Protractor does not work if i do not move mouse cursor on the application page

Tags: protractor

My protractor tests work fine when i place mouse cursor on the application page (especially on the text fields or near to that) and i need to move the mouse cursor then only the protractor proceeds filling the fields and proceeds further.

But if i dont move the mouse it never fills the data even though the page is visibly ready. I have increased the allScriptsTimeout in configuration file to 60000, still it waits whatever the time i mention and timesout with this error "Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 60 seconds". It is really puzziling me what was the issue. I have also given "untrackOutstandingTimeouts: true" in configuration file. still the issue is there.

Why is that protractor is able to continue without any issue ONLY WHEN i move the mouse cursor on the application page? If i dont move the mouse why is it not working and simply waiting?

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Are you testing an angular application? Does your webpage have some kind of timeout or outstanding request that is preventing the page from being ready until the mouse is moved onto the page or focusing some text field? Does the page work with any other actions besides trying to fill in text fields? Can you share your test that is failing in your question?

Comment: I have posted the details in the answer as the comment is limiting me to enter all the details.